# Blazor Fluent UI example doesn't generate styles.css

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, fluent-ui

I am looking to try out the Fluent UI example template and noticed some strange behavior.

In [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/blazor#styles) it states that you need to add this to your `_Layout.cshtml`.

> `<link href="{PROJECT_NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

So if I had a project called `Web.csproj`, the link href would be `Web.styles.css`. However, this doesn't seem to resolve, even for a default project:

[image: The project's name is FluentUI-Server and the URL to the stylesheet is FluentUI_Server.styles.css]

[image: The browser shows a 404 retrieving FluentUI_Server.styles.css]

Even when I tried with a project named 'Web', it wasn't able to resolve the css file. I notice the UI is styled with a "constructed stylesheet" but it's annoying that I'd see these errors in the console if everything is OK. Am I missing something?

Comment: Even when I tried with a project named 'Web', it wasn't able to resolve the css file----could you show a minimal example that could reproduce the issue?

Comment: I think your answer below is correct: The name of the project confused the template into linking a filename that didn't match the project.

Comment: My `Web` example was actually with another solution I have that is originally a asp.net MVC app that I am trying to append some Blazor components into while I migrate the whole project. I suspect something with routes is causing this stylesheet to not resolve :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue:

[image]

In my opinion,"-" is not allowed in the namespace(I'd never added "-" in project name),and it was convertered to "_" in your codes when create the project,but your assembly name is `FluentUI-Server` instead of `FluentUI_Server`

just modify

```
<link href="FluentUI_Server1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<link href="FluentUI-Server1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It's ok now:

[image]

Comment: The issue ended up being that I misread the instructions (or they weren't clear). It's not necessarily the name of the project (.csproj). Rather, it's the name of the assembly or namespace of the project. Since I nest my projects (ex: `{AppName}.Web`) it wasn't finding it even though the csproj was `Web`). Once I set href to `~/{AppName}.UI.Web.styles.css` it found it right away!